# Last not null price every x interval

Tags: kdb

How can I get the last not null price every x interval

```
quote:([] sym:5#`aapl; time: 08:59 09:27 09:40 09:45 09:46;price: 10 0Ni 30 40 50 )
```

.i.e if I wanted 15min intervals between 09:00 & 10:00

```
time   price
09:00  10
09:15  10
09:30  10
09:45  40
10:00  50
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you essentially want an asof join:

```
q)aj[`sym`time;([]sym:`aapl;time:09:00+00:15*til 5);update fills price by sym from quote]
sym  time  price
----------------
aapl 09:00 10
aapl 09:15 10
aapl 09:30 10
aapl 09:45 40
aapl 10:00 50
```

NOTE - this would be fine in memory but the fills on an historical table would not be efficient

Comment: 1. Wouldn't it be better to fill the resulting AJ table rather than the HDB? - this is assuming there is just 1 sym
2. How can I do this nicely with multiple syms efficiently? Basically trade table would be all the syms for all the times?
3. How can I get the time column properly as I won't know the number of rows (til 5). I'll only know the start/end time

Comment: 1. No, filling after the AJ would be incorrect. Imagine you have `quote:([]time:08:50 09:01 09:14 09:16;price:10 100 0N 200)` then if you fill after the AJ you'd be filling forward the price of 10 into the 09:15 bucket when it should be filling forward the price of 100 from 09:01 (which would be the case if you fill prior to the AJ).

Comment: 2. The AJ already handles multiple syms. 3. You can count how many 15min intervals are between your start and end times and replace my "5" with that count. Of course it depends on whether your intervals needs to start on an even hour mark, or starts whenever your start time is. i.e. do you want 15 mins intervals starting 09:00 09:15 etc or 15 mins intervals starting from your start time, e.g. 08:57 09:12 etc

Comment: We can also just filter out nulls from hdb before aj and avoid fills. Example: aj[\`sym\`time;([]sym:\`aapl;time:09:00+00:15*til 5);select from quote where not null price].  Can add more filters to hdb queries based on time range and sym list to make it efficient.

Comment: I think that would actually make it less efficient @Rahul ! The only efficient where clause on the quote table in an on-disk disk AJ is `date=`. @Rezzy - if you have nulls in your quote table on disk then it will be impossible to do an efficient AJ which handles the nulls. You woud have had to have forward-filled the nulls prior to writedown. Your only option might be to use AJ filtering only on `date=` in the quote table, then forward-filling prices after the AJ (which will give inaccurate results as mentioned above)

Comment: Yes @terrylynch partition column will be required in filter for on disk query.  Did not mention that as thats normally the default in  hdb queries filters. Partition  filter in combination with more filters should give good enough performance.  But that all depends on the setup and  the expected performance Rezzy wants.

Comment: @Rezzy if this is a regular ask then depending on your setup you can also look into setting up a separate job to store last not null  price by date, sym , time window.